# How to delete procedure or function from Package

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Suppose you create a package in Oracle 10g and has defined a procedure and a function inside the package.
Now, How to delete a particular procedure or function in the package created, without physically DROPPING the package?? i.e. without using DROP PACKAGE package_name

I was wondering if i could actually perform the above action. Thank you in advance for any suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since all objects in a package are stored as a unit, Oracle won't allow you to modify, drop or add packages or functions without replacing the whole package body.

You can find some discussion on the subject [at the Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=612503).

Comment: Thanks !! So if you want to make some modifications in the package body; we would need to DROP the entire package first and rewrite the entire package specification and body together.

Comment: @Rishu Yes, there is a way to do that in a not too inconvenient way at the end of the linked page (ie exporting the package to an editor)

Comment: @Rishu:You Don't need to drop a package for deleting procedure or function, only remove the procedure/function from the package and then compile the package .

Comment: if it is just the "drop package" statement you want to avoid, that is no problem. you can use "create or replace package" to either create a new package or replace an already existing one.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If the procedure or function is private to the package - it doesn't appear in the package spec - then one does not need to `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE`; one only needs to `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY.`  Oracle does grants and tracks dependencies against the package specification, not the package body.